Is there a way to run tsx with endent and similar Tagged Template Literals?
Running npx tsx test.ts of this:
// test.ts
import endent from 'endent';

const stringProcessor = (str: TemplateStringsArray) => {
  return `  ${str.join()}`;
};

function main() {
  // console.log(stringProcessor`test`); // this works
  console.log(endent`test`); // this FAILS
}

main();

Produces the following error:
TypeError: endent is not a function
    at main (test.ts:9:15)
    at <anonymous> (test.ts:12:1)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:120:12)

Is there any configuration I can make to resolve this or is it a bug in tsx?
System:

MacOS: 14.2.1 (Arm)
tsx: v4.7.2
node: v21.7.1

(I've reported the issue in the tsx repo)

try running console.log(endent) and console.log(endent.default`test`)

The tsc does seem to resolve it correctly. I shouldn't need to use .default just for tsx?

I don't know why this happens but I have faced this type of issue before with certain libraries, I guess its because of es modules / tree shaking feature ?. I couldn't use it as we use normally,  no matter what i tried (like using import { default as something } and others) in the past.
